# How to show permissions to add or change a Django model in Group or user permission list on Admin site?

Tags: django, django-models, model, django-admin, django-permissions

I am able to run a Django Admin site and when I login as the SuperUser I'm able to modify my model as well. This part works perfectly.
When I login as a user that is NOT a super user, the user does not see an option to modify this Model. When I logged in as a Super User and tried to give this user/group the permission to modify this model from the permission list, I couldn't find this permission in the list.

I see the following permissions:

- admin|log entry|
- .
- .
- auth|group|...
- auth|message|...
- auth|permission|...
- content types|...
- sessions|...

but nothing related to my ModelAdmin. My admin.py looks as follows:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from pl.models import *

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Can only a super-user edit models specified via ModelAdmin? What if I want to permission a group to be able to do so for select models. Any way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already run `syncdb` and the permissions are still not there, then you must not have your app listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Otherwise, Django would automatically create them.

Additionally, you mention "nothing related to my ModelAdmin". The permissions are created for *models*, not `ModelAdmin`s. You may have just mistyped that, but if you're looking for something related to the `ModelAdmin` itself, that might be your problem.

Comment: +1 as your post pointed me in the right direction. I think the problem is with my directory structure. My INSTALLED_APPS has 'abc' as the app name while my models.py is in abc/xyz while my urls.py and settings.py are in abc/. If I change the app name in INSTALLED_APPS to abc/xyz the permissions are generated but then the rest of my stuff breaks (normal requests)

Comment: "abc" is likely your project, then, and "xyz" is your app. Depending on how your `PYTHONPATH` is setup, you may or may not need to prepend the project to the app in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Regardless, you use a `.` rather than a `/` in this scenario. So, it should either be `'abc.xyz',` or just `'xyz',`

Comment: I did use abc.xyz and the permissions were generated. However other urls broke. I'm gonna play with it a bit more but I think I know what the problem is. manage.py wasn't finding the correct app via INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do that. Try running `python manage.py syncdb` again.

Comment: I've already tried that and did so again and checked the database as well. Those permissions are just not being created. (Did a select * from auth_permission)